# Katalon generated path for command line doesn't exist

Tags: automated-tests, katalon-studio

I want to run some Katalon tests on cmd on Mac but when I copied the generated path and I want to run it in cmd I got an error "No such a file o directory".

Before I did it I typed in "CD applications" and then I have pasted the below code in:

```
./Katalon\ Studio.app/Contents/MacOS/katalon --args -noSplash  -runMode=console -projectPath="/Users/grzegorzspytek/Desktop/Baseline/Baseline tests/Baseline tests.prj" -retry=2 -retryFailedTestCases=true -testSuitePath="Test Suites/Cnt - Button test" -executionProfile="default" -browserType="Chrome"
```

In this case, I don't know what is wrong, anyone has any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first need to navigate to the folder of your Katalon Studio build (Applications folder on Mac).

And than run the following command from there

```
./Katalon\ Studio.app/Contents/MacOS/katalon --args -noSplash -runMode=console -projectPath="/Users/grzegorzspytek/Desktop/Baseline/Baseline tests/Baseline tests.prj" -retry=2 -retryFailedTestCases=true -testSuitePath="Test Suites/Cnt - Button test" -executionProfile="default" -browserType="Chrome"
```

Answer (score 1):

Your generated cmd works on my machine. I think you need to double check the Application folder.

```html
cd /Applications
```